# Custom reset password system on Parse Server

Tags: php, heroku, parse-platform, password-recovery, parse-server

Since parse server don't have the Reset Password system yet, I'm trying to do it myself, but I can't find the way to change the User password for a new one.

I'm running parse server in Heroku, I created the web in PHP (Parse PHP SDK with the master key) with a token generator that sends an email to the user and validates the token, but when I try to change the password I get: "cannot modify user".

Any way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

That error is normally thrown when an attempt is made at changing a user while either logged in as another user or not logged in at all. For resetting an email you should be able to get around it by specifying the master key.

Comment: The user is not logged in because he lost the password.. and he's to create a new one. Yes, I'm using the master key, but still i get that error.

Comment: Of course, my bad, will take another look. Can you change other properties of the user? Can you edit the question and include the code you are using?

Comment: I found my error, when you're trying to save an object with the master key you need to add true as the parameter (useMasterKey) of the save function. `$object2->save(true);`